# Problems with numpy divide

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to use numpy divide to perform division on arrays and I have two arrays and I call it as follows:

```
log_norm_images = np.divide(diff_images, b_0)
```

I get the error:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (96,96,55,64) (96,96,55).
```

These are the shapes of the ndarrays respectively.

Now, in my python shell, I do the following tests:

```
 x = np.random.rand((100, 100, 100))
 y = np.random.rand((100, 100))
```

and

```
np.divide(x, y)
```

runs without any errors. I am not sure why this works and not my case.

Comment: They are not the same shapes though.

Comment: But neither are the arrays in the test case and I am guessing it divides it along the last axes. I am not sure why the random case works and mine does not. Taking a simpler example. x = np.random.rand(2, 2, 2) y = np.random.rand(2, 2) np.divide(x, y) and examining the values shows it does the thing I expect it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attempting to broadcast a 4-D array together with a 3-D array.  Based on NumPy's broadcasting behavior, this will only succeed if for each corresponding dimension, the dimensions are either equal or one of them is 1.  Here's why it mismatches:

```
Your 4-D array:  96 x 96 x 55 x 64
Your 3-D array:       96 x 96 x 55
                           ^     ^
                           Mismatching dimensions
```

Your operation will probably work if your pad out/reshape your 3-D array (which would no longer be 3-D I suppose) to explicitly have the shape (96, 96, 55, 1).  Then it would look like:

```
Your 4-D array:  96 x 96 x 55 x 64
Your 3-D array:  96 x 96 x 55 x 1
                                 ^
                                This is acceptable for the broadcast behavior
```

This link to the SciPy/NumPy documentation gets into this in more detail:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

Comment: Ah...ok, I thought it was comparing from the other side! That did the trick. Thanks!